# How to get value from database and setColor to many JButton

Tags: java, sql

I have 1 table in database

```
TableRoom
- NoRoom
- Status
```

and i have

```
room 
101,
102,
103,
104,
105,
201,
202,
203, 
204,
205
```

My problem is how to call a database and specify the colors for the buttons. if the status of the room was filled with the buttons should be colored red, and if the status of the room was empty, the button should be green

this mycode

```
JButton [] arr = new JButton[10];    
.........

if(r.next()){    
   status = r.getString("status");    
   noRoom = r.getString("noRoom");    
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){    
      if (arr[i].getActionCommand().equals(noRoom)){
         r.beforeFirst();
         while(r.next()){
            arr[i].setBackground(Color.red);
         }    
         s.close(); 
         c.close();
      } else {
         arr[i].setBackground(Color.green);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What part are you having an issue with?  Calling the database?  Determine the status of the room?  Changing the color of the buttons?  What's the structure of your code?  How are the buttons managed? How are the linked to a particular rooms?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating a POJO of the `Room`... something like...

```
public class Room {

    private final int roomNumber;
    private final boolean status;

    public Room(int roomNumber, boolean status) {
        this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getRoomNumber() {
        return roomNumber;
    }

    public boolean isOccupied() {
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.roomNumber;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Room other = (Room) obj;
        if (this.roomNumber != other.roomNumber) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

for example.  This allows you to contain all the information related to a individual room into a single class.  Also, through the use of `equals` and `hashcode`, we don't need to keep track of a single instance for each `Room` object, but could have multiple instances, but which will equate to the same thing, this will make a little more sense after you....

Create a "general" utility method to load the rooms

```
protected List<Room> getRooms() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = null;
    List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<>(25);
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from TableRoom")) {
        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Room room = new Room(rs.getInt("NoRoom"), rs.getBoolean("Status"));
                rooms.add(room);
            }
        }
    } 
    return rooms;
}
```

All this does is queries the database, loads the data into a series of `Room`s and returns a `List`, nice.  Now, when ever you want to check the database, you could simply call this method and get a `List` of `Room`s

Next, you need some way to link the `Room` and it's button, a simple `Map` would suffice for this...

```
private Map<Room, JButton> buttons;
```

Next, you need to initialise the values...

```
    buttons = new HashMap<>(25);

    try {
        List<Room> rooms = getRooms();
        for (Room room : rooms) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(Integer.toString(room.getRoomNumber()));
            buttons.put(room, btn);
            updateRoomStatus(room);
            // Add button to UI as required
        }
    } catch (SQLException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, when you want to update the status of the buttons you would simply do something like...

```
    try {
        List<Room> rooms = getRooms();
        for (Room room : rooms) {
            updateRoomStatus(room);
        }
    } catch (SQLException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And finally, you would need a simple utility method, which when provided with a `Room` could update the state of the associated button, something like...

```
protected void updateRoomStatus(Room room) {

    JButton btn = buttons.get(room);
    if (btn != null) {
        if (room.isOccupied()) {
            btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else {
            btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, this is a pretty simple example, a more complex example would have you maintain a single instance of a `Room` and update it from the data in the database.  This means that if you were to change the state any given `Room`, that change would be reflected in all references you had to the `Room`.

Also, this assumes that the number of rooms doesn't change between initialising the data and updating it, which seems to make sense, but is worth pointing out.

Have a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details